# React fetch hangs when user navigates backward

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, back

This problem is totally mystifying me. Basically, a user can use the site that I have created with no issues as long as they either type urls in directly or use buttons to navigate. If a user hits the back button on the browser, the site will bring them to the previous page they were on... but any fetch there will fail to be sent. The fetch will not throw errors. It will simply sit in `pending` indefinitely. Note the screenshot below showing a single request which has been pending for over ten minutes:

[image]

This happens with perfect consistency to every page in the site. If someone triggers a `hard reload`, or clicks on `explanation` next to the hung request in chrome dev tools, the page will load normally.

I'm not even sure what code to include. I'm including below an arbitrary example component:

**Component hangs after user comes back with browser back button**

```
import React from 'react'
import './UsersView.scss'
import {fetchGET} from '../../../../utils/apiUtils'
import UserRow from './UserRow'

class UsersView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users : []
    };

    this.componentWillMount = this.componentWillMount.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    var roles = [];
    var rolesLookup = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("roleById"));
    var idLookup = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("idByRole"));

    var permissionLookup = {};
    let filter = {is_active:true};
    fetchGET('/v1/permission/', filter).then(function (json) { //retrieve user context
      if(json.code){
        this.setAlertBox(json.message);
      }
      else{
        var permissions = json.Permission;
        for(var i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++){
          var permission = permissions[i];
          if(permission.user_id in permissionLookup){
            permissionLookup[permission.user_id].push(permission.role_id);
          }
          else{
            permissionLookup[permission.user_id] = [permission.role_id];
          }
        }
      fetchGET('/v1/user/', null).then(function (json) { //retrieve user context
        if(json.code){
          this.setAlertBox(json.message);
        }
        else{
          var users = json.User;
          var userRows = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
            var user = users[i];
            let roleIds = permissionLookup[user.uid];
            var newRow = <UserRow user={user} roles={Object.keys(idLookup)} key={i.toString()} rowId={i.toString()} role={rolesLookup[roleIds[0]]} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>;
            userRows.push(newRow);
          }
          this.setState({'users': userRows});
        }
      }.bind(this))
     }
    }.bind(this))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="usersView">
        <table className="table table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Roles</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {this.state.users}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UsersView
```

Below is the code defining how the fetch works:

```
var fetchGET = function fetchGET(endpoint, parameters){
  var url = process.env.__API__ + endpoint; // eslint-disable-line no-undef
  if(parameters){
    url = url + '?';
    for (var key in parameters){
      url=url + key + '=' + parameters[key] + ',';
    }
    url = url.slice(0, -1); //remove the last comma from the end of the params
  }
  var headers = buildHeaders();
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
  }).then(function (response) {
    return response.json()
  })
}
```

I've been unable to find any similar problem on the net. If anyone has any insight I would very sincerely appreciate it.

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that this problem only surfaces in the development build out of webpack. The production build doesn't suffer from it.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code of `buildHeaders` per request:

```
function buildHeaders(){
  var headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
  var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if(token !== null) {
    headers['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + token;
  }
  return headers;
}
```

Comment: If you are totally stuck, I would recommend create a copy of your current project, but including files from the base upwards (i.e. from `main.js`, to router, to container, etc) incrementally and seeing at which point you encounter infinite loops or something similar.

Comment: can you reveal the code of `buildHeaders()` function or at least output to the console the headers values?

Comment: sames is happening to me. Did u resolve this somehow?

Comment: I was not able to discover a solution. Since it only occurs in the development build, I have just been living with it. Not ideal, but I spent too much time on it already for a problem that I can workaround. If you figure it out then make sure to post!